# Laptop second ssd are read only after swapping primary win11 ssd for ubuntu22 ssd

Tags: ssd, readonly

I had dramas installing win11, ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 20.04 on my primary ssd.

After the struggle got win11 recovered and formatted the second ssd. (new simple volume)
I then replaced the primary ssd and installed ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded it to 22.04.
Yes I intend to swap primary ssd's when switching between OS's. (not that often)

So: Ubuntu found the second ssd, file permissions display read,write,execute but I can't copy to, or delete anything on the drive.
research: suggest that file systems on second drive differs, so ubuntu can only read it. But/or can't change the write protection?

I don't want to use the m2 ssd as an external backup/storage device I would like to use it internally between the OS's.

How do I do this?